# How to add aliases in yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii-modules

I have extracted mdmsoft extension in my `backend/extensions/mdm` folder. Added aliases in backend config main.php

```
'aliases' => [
    '@mdm/admin' => '@backend/extensions/mdm'
]
```

Added module as

```
[
    'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module'
        ]
    ]
],
```

It returns me error.Failed to instantiate component or class "**mdm\admin\Module**".

How I can manage the config file that MDM works from my backend folder

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam

Comment: did you use composer?

Comment: yes but i deleted it form vendor folder and download it from git hub and extract there

Comment: @AhmedSunny the part i am missing is the alias i am adding is not replace mdm/admin to backend /extension/mdm

Comment: @AhmedSunny i can change it like this         'admin' => [
            'class' => 'backend\extensions\mdm\Module',
          // 'layout' => '@backend/views/layouts/admin',
            'controllerMap' => [
                'assignment' => [
                    'class' => 'backend\extensions\mdm\controllers\AssignmentController',
                ]
            ],
        ], but the problem is i have to change the namspace from each controller and models

Comment: if its in vendor then use vendor instead of backend like this      '@mdm/admin' => '@vendor/mdmsoft/yii2-admin',

Comment: @AhmedSunny i have to customize so i want it to backend

Comment: what are you trying to do here dude, why not using `composer` to install the extension? and the way you are tagging my username does not send me any notification you have to remove spaces when tagging users like  `@firstnamelastname` rather than `@firstname lastname`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Salam how are you bro.Basically i am using mdm,auditlog and yii2-cms extensions in my project i have to make some changes in these extensions.So i want these in my backend folder.for this when i just try to add the mdm soft using Archive method and added aliases it return the Failed to instantiate component or class "mdm\admin\Module". error. If i have done this i will follow it for other extensions

Comment: if you need to customize it, extend its main class, and override the functions which you need to change but install it via composer.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam why the mdm soft is not working when i install it via Archive method?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam   this one work admin' => [ 'class' => 'backend\extensions\mdm\Module', // 'layout' => '@backend/views/layouts/admin', 'controllerMap' => [ 'assignment' => [ 'class' => 'backend\extensions\mdm\controllers\AssignmentController', ] ], ], but the problem is i have to change the namspace from each controller and models

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i just need is this to work     'aliases' => [
        '@mdm/admin' => 'backend/extensions/mdm',
    ],

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I need some customization in views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to add line below:

```
Yii::setAlias('@mdm', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend/extensions/mdm');
```

into common/config/bootstrap.php ?